# Does Playwright support Island Browser?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I have a requirement to open webpage in Island browser, is there any support or workaround for this in Playwright with Java?

I have implemented multi-browser support in framework but looking for Island driver support if available in Playwright.

Answer (score 0):

File a feature request in github https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md&title=%5BFeature%5D